# Threejs rotation from right-handed system to left-handed system unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, three.js

I'm getting Euler angle value from Threejs to unity3d. But im facing problem those are not working good. Because Unity3D is left handed with +z, but Threejs is right handed coordinates with -z.

How can solve this problem. can any one you give the suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To receive a proper answer, you'll need to show what you have done so far, ideally as a [mcve]. 
Then tell us what exactly does not work (explicitly you may say e.g. "I am experiencing this but I am expecting that"). 
See our guide How to ask for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by inverting the Y rotation. If you also want to convert the position, invert the X axis

```
yRotationUnity=-yRotationThreeJS;
xUnity=-xThreeJS;
```